# Informatica HTTP Transformation

Tags: http, etl, informatica-powercenter, informatica

I am facing problems with Informatica HTTP transformation.

In the HTTP transformation, the integration service connects to the HTTP Server with a request and the servers response is recorded in the target table.

I was planning to build a web application which will take a user name and print the password in the next page and the password will be recorded in the target table. I had problems establishing connectivity with the database and now simply looking for websites that are already deployed which can make this possible.

Can you suggest any website? A very simple transformation will do. A simple website or any help to make a simple HTTP transformation possible will be of great help.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple PHP web page that accept UserId and print password. You can use Wamp server on windows to run PHP site on local machine.

WHile setting HHTP transformation HTTP Properties specify Base Url as the page address where you are submitting the form (i.e web page address you specified in **action** part of html form tag. In this case /httptrans/submit.php)

Note: Port name in HTTP transformation shall be same as of what is mentioned in form elements.

Below is sample code.

### httptrans/login.php

```
<html>
<body>
<form action=httptrans/submit.php' method='post'>
User: <input type=text name='userid' /><br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

### httptrans/submit.php

```
<?php

$user=$_POST['userid'];

/* your database operation */

echo "User added";  // this output is sent to http transformation as response

?>
```

This should work.